# How to call/Link GLPK for Windows in Makefile? [cannot find -lglpk]

Tags: makefile, glpk

I am trying to use an open-source program called PumpKin, which is a plasma kinetics solver.

It works with Makefile, and the Makefile uses g++ and GLPK. So I installed g++ via MinGW, downloaded GLPK for Windows, unzipped it, and placed it in C drive. g++ was not problematic. The environmental variable was also added in Path like below:

```
C:\MinGW\bin
C:\glpk-5.0\w64
```

The following is the entire code of the Makefile.

```
OBJ = PumpKin.o pk_IO.o pk_Array.o pk_Pathways.o pk_Print.o
#Auxiliary.o Tests.o Print.o Pathways.o Optimize.o OptimizeDifferent.o

#CFLAGS    = -std=gnu++0x -g 
DFLAGS    = -DCOMPILING_HOSTNAME=\"$(HOSTNAME)\"
INCLUDE_DIRS += -I/opt/local/include -I$(HOME)/include
#LFLAGS    =  -stdlib=libc++
LIBS =  -L/opt/local/lib -lglpk -lm 
#LIBS += = -L/usr/local/NLopt/lib -lnlopt -lm
CC   = g++
LINK = g++

all:    pumpkin

%.o:    %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -O3 -o $@ -c $< 
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -g -o $@ -c $< 

%.o:    %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -g -o $@ -c $< 

pumpkin:  $(OBJ)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -std=gnu++0x $(OBJ) -o $@ $(LIBS)


clean:  
rm *.o *.*~ pumpkin 2> /dev/null
```

But when I type "make" in the prompt, it returns an error that says "cannot find -lglpk"

```
D:\workfiles\pumpkin-1.5\src>make

g++  -std=gnu++0x PumpKin.o pk_IO.o pk_Array.o pk_Pathways.o pk_Print.o -o pumpkin -L/opt/local/lib -lglpk -lm
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglpk
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess it is because the directory of GLPK is not properly directed, but I am not sure.

I am very new to Makefile programming, and I actually do not understand a single command in this Makefile.

I am studying about it, but I wonder if this is a simple problem so someone may be able to fix it at a glance.

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Your problem is not "_Makefile programming_", it is a compilation and linking problem. You "_placed it in C drive_": OK but the next question is where? Your Makefile tells `g++` that the GLPK library is in `/opt/local/lib`. Is it really in `/opt/local/lib`? If it is not, did you put it in one of the other standard locations for libraries (`/usr/lib`, for instance)?

Comment: Please do not use images to show just text. Copy paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thank you. I removed the image. And I meant literally C drive, so the directory is "C:\glpk-5.0\w64" Can I use like 'LIBS =  C:\glpk-5.0\w64 -lglpk -lm'? In fact I tried, but it returns additional errors saying 
'c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\glpk-5.0\w64: Permission denied'

Comment: Yes, that's it, `g++` does not know where to find the GLPK library because it is not in a standard location and not in the `/opt/local/lib` that your Makefile adds to these standard locations. I am not familiar at all with Windows and all these environments that try to mimic GNU/Linux under Windows but you could maybe try `LIBS = -Lc:/glpk-5.0/w64 -L/opt/local/lib -lglpk -lm`.